How to get a BigQuery Model DDL script?
I need to get a BigQuery Model DDL script. I read models with the help of the Google client library. I have found no traces so far of DDL script in the com.google.cloud.bigquery.Model provided by the client library.
And I do not see how to get the DDL script through SQL either.
